# how to write your own right click menu and disable the default using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, right-click

I successfully disabled the right click event on the page that I am working on using jquery. I want to create a customize right click menu. How can I do this? Does this need relevant css setting to get it working (i.e. "position")?

Comment: I'd recommend you not to do this, unless you give the user the option to turn it off - its annoying, and breaks the "web" way of doing things. For example, if a user wanted to save a image from your website, they wouldnt be able to do so easily (they can still do it, just need to go thru hoops).

Comment: Not a problem since I am using it to an application for a group on an intranet.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are various jQuery context menu plugins out there, ready to use:

- [jQueryContextMenu](https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/)
- [jQuery Context Menu Plugin](http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/lib/contextmenu/)

Comment: can I add new functions (aside from default copy,edit, paste .. etc) on context menu plugin?

Answer (score 3):

This example works, though it is cheesy.  What you could do in your contextmenu handler is show a DIV at a specific location on the screen with items of your choosing.  As far as I know, there is no way to customize the items within the context menu that appears when you right-click on elements.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Context menu test</title>  
    <style type="text/css">
      .element {
        background-color: blue;
        height: 300px;
        width: 300px;
      }

      .popup {
        background-color: red;
        border: 1px solid black;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        position: absolute;
       }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
          $(".element").contextmenu
          (
            function(e) {
              $("div.popup").remove();
              $("<div class='popup'>Hi</div>").appendTo("body")
                .css("left", e.pageX)
                .css("top", e.pageY)
                .show();
              e.preventDefault();  // return false; also works
            }
          );
        }
      );

      $.fn.contextmenu = function(func) {
        return this.bind("contextmenu", func);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="element"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is this plugin too: [Audero Context Menu](https://github.com/AurelioDeRosa/Audero-Context-Menu). It is free and very simple to use.